# Rails: around_* callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have read the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html, but don't understand when the `around_*` callbacks are triggered in relation to `before_*` and `after_*`.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`around_*` callbacks are invoked **before** the action, then when you want to invoke the action itself, you `yield` to it, then continue execution. That's why it's called **`around`**

The order goes like this: `before`, `around`, `after`.

So, a typical `around_save` would look like this:

```
def around_save
   #do something...
   yield #saves
   #do something else...
end
```

Comment: It makes sense and is not in the official Rails guides.

Comment: Honestly kind of surprised it's been 10+ years and the only "documentation" available is through StackOverflow. Is this information available in any official docs, or it's still something you just gotta "figure out" how to use?

Answer (score 153):

The around_* callback is called around the action and inside the before_* and after_* actions. For example:

```
class User
  def before_save
    puts 'before save'
  end

  def after_save
    puts 'after_save'
  end

  def around_save
    puts 'in around save'
    yield # User saved
    puts 'out around save'
  end
end

User.save
  before save
  in around save
  out around save
  after_save
=> true
```

Comment: For me this is the most _illuminating_ answer. Thanks friend.