# Mongoid 3 callbacks: before_upsert vs. before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

For Mongoid 3+, is there a diagram/description of the various callbacks? http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/callbacks.html

For example, what's the difference between `before_upsert` vs. `before_save`. Isn't a `save` caused by an `insert` or `update` call? Or does `save` also get called by `destroy`?

Also, what's difference between `before_xxx` and `around_xxx`?

Answer (score 0):

With before_xxx the code is executed before the action and with around_xxx you have the option to execute code before and after the action itself.

For example, imagine you want to update all the user belongings after destroy a user project (User has_many :proyects and Project belongs_to User) :

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  around_destroy :destroy_belongings

  def destroy_belongings
    old_user = self.user
    ...
    # Here the before_destroy ends.

    yield # Here the destroy is performed itself.

    # Here the after_destroy starts. It's needed to do this operation after destroy the project because, imagine, the update_belongings method calculates something related to the current number of proyects. And a simple after_destroy is not useful as we would have lost the project owner.

    old_user.update_belongings
  end
end
```

You can also see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998584/717506) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711109/717506). Moreover [this other article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=2) could be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Josal. How do I indicate whether I want to execute before or after action itself?

Comment: With around_xxx you can use yield to set it. I'll update my answer because here I cannot include new lines.