# Whenever a User object is created, create UserInfo object too

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever a `User` object is created, I want a `UserInfo` object to be created too, and linked to it.

Unfortunately this does not create any `UserInfo`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_info
  ...

  def init
    self.user_info = user_info
    self.save!
  end
```

Why is the `init` method not called? How to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sombe's technique is right, but his details aren't ideal. In fact, since `create_user_info` is already a method on `User` instances, all you want is something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_info
  before_create :create_user_info
end
```

**Edit:** `init` doesn't do anything particularly magical under Rails (I... don't think it does under basic Ruby either - are you thinking of `initialize`? I'll assume you are). `initialize` is fired off when an instance of the Ruby class is created in memory. That's divorced by quite some margin from an instance of the model being created in the database; a new class instance could be due to you calling `build` (and not saving yet), or even due to reading an instance out of the database.

If you want to step in on database operations, you need to make use of the ActiveRecord callbacks. You might find [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249475/ruby-on-rails-callback-what-is-difference-between-before-save-and-before-creat/6249572#6249572) useful.

Answer (score 1):

**before_save** callback triggers on create and update.
I'd suggest to use after_create because before_create can return errors

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_info
  ...

  after_create do
    create_user_info
end
```

Comment: That's true, before_create could return errors. In which case you have to ask; Do I want to create a User even if the UserInfo creation fails (use after_create), or do I want to fail the whole User creation in that case (use before_create)?

Comment: actually I'd doing such tasks another way. In controller **@user.valid? && @user_info.valid? && @user.save**. Another way is to use **acceptence_nested_attributes**

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, use a before_save filter instead of init like this:

```
before_save :create_user_info

...

private

def create_user_info 
   user_info = UserInfo.new
   if user_info.save
       self.user_info_id = user_info.id
   end
end
```