# Is :on => :create valid for a before_save callback in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, before-save

As you know, `before_save` callbacks are executed prior to `before_create` callbacks.

Therefore, some people have suggested that in would be better to use `before_save :method, :on => :create` instead of `before_create` so that the callback method is executed at the right time in relation to other callbacks (such as autosave callbacks).  See, for example, this [Pivotal Labs blog post](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/activerecord-callbacks-autosave-before-this-and-that-etc), and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967362/1121817).

However, as far as I can tell, the `:on => :create` option does not achieve the desired effect on a `before_save` callback.  In other words, the callback is executed for every save regardless of whether it is a create or not.

The `:on => :create` option *does* appear to be valid for `before_validation` callbacks, though.

Could someone confirm whether the `:on => :create` is supposed to work for a `before_save`?  Did it work in previous versions of Rails and is now broken, or are the aforementioned links simply mistaken?

Assuming `:on => :create` is not valid, is the following acceptable, and/or is there a better way?

```
before_save :callback_method, :if => :new_record?
```

Thank you.

Comment: I submitted a PR for Rails to add strict argument checking: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30919

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're right, there is no `:on` option for `before_save` callback.
But, I don't understand, why use `before_save` instead of `before_create`.
`before_create` callback will be called right after `before_save`.

Of course, you can use `before_save :callback_method, :if => :new_record?`. But I personally don't like this solution - what if I need to add conditions in the `:if` option?

If one have a dependency between `before_save` and `before_create` callbacks, I`d suggest, to combine 2 callbacks. For instance (pseudocode):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :prepare_x
  before_save :do_something_with_x

  def prepare_x
    @x = 10
  end


  # will not work, because `prepare_x` called after `do_something_with_x`
  def do_something_with_x
    @a = 100 / @x
  end
end

# ||
# ||
# \/

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :do_something_with_x

  def do_something_with_x
    @x = 10 if new_record?
    @a = 100 / @x
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and in particular for confirming that `:on => :create` is not valid.  Combining callbacks sounds like it may be a good idea in the general case, but I'm not sure it applies well to the specific case of trying to prepare data for a callback created by an autosave association, does it?

Comment: Regarding your question of why I want to use before_save instead of before_create: this is explained well in the blog post I referenced.  A callback is being created by core Rails code via an autosave association.  The callback I want to create needs to be executed before the autosave callback, and a before_create callback would occur too late.

Comment: It's too bad that `before_save :on => :create` fails silently. It would be nice if it either worked or threw an exception.

Comment: When testing I notice that _before_create_ is called when **creating** objects, but _before_save_ is called when **updating** objects.

[This](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_create) mentions that before_create is called "before" Base.save (may seem confusing). [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)  indicates before_create is called "after" before_save

There are nice explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249475/ruby-on-rails-callback-what-is-difference-between-before-save-and-before-crea/6967362#6967362) too.