# before_create - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Ruby on Rails Callback, what is difference between :before_save and :before_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249475/ruby-on-rails-callback-what-is-difference-between-before-save-and-before-crea)

I'm looking to replace Ruby on Rails current id from /1, /2, /3, etc to a randomly generated URL, for example /csd8dsv68dvs.

After looking into creating it, I found this in the post model

```
before_create { self.code = SecureRandom.hex(5) }
```

What does the before_create do and how can I implement the random id?

#### Update

It seems I got one part wrong. I'm not looking to change the ID, I just want to change the URL to a random string that a user won't be able to guess.

Comment: It is a duplicate but that's not the only thing he/she is asking. Notice he/she needs to know how to replace the default id rails generate with a random one.

Comment: Definitely take a look at the callback API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great gem to help you with alternatives to a resource `:id` as the identfier through a route is **[friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)**. There is even **[a RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)** on it.

`before_create` is an **[ActiveRecord callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)** and is well explained both here on SO (as others have commented) and in the API.

If you chose to use the raw

```
before_create { self.code = SecureRandom.hex(5) }
```

You could modify your controller action to find the resource using this code instead of the id.

```
def some_action
  @resource = ModelClass.find_by_code!(params[:id])
end
```

You'd pass the `:code` attribute to routes for the resource in your views

```
resource_path(@resource.code)
```

where `resource_path` is the route method for your resource.

Comment: Man, you type faster than I do :-)

Comment: Dont forget to index the `code` column

Comment: What do I have to add in my views?

Comment: My answer already tells you what you need to put your view: the path method for the route to your resource, specifying the `:code` attribute. If you use **friendly_id** like everyone is suggesting, specifying the `:code` typically isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would *strongly* advise against replacing the Rails id, but if you mean that you want to change the URL to something less predictable, then you're on the right path.

This is a very similar problem to one solved by creating "pretty URLs" which has been solved many times, for example with the [Friendly ID gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).  Perhaps you'll want to fork the gem and call it "Unfriendly ID" :-)

Whether the gem works out of the box or not, the method is straightforward -- read the code and learn from the guy who wrote it!

Comment: I tried the Friendly ID gem although it didn't really help. I see what you mean although this application allows users to create things privately, I'd prefer if the URL was random to stop users from guessing the URLs.

Comment: I am not sure why the gem wouldn't help.  I understand the goal -- it's perfectly reasonable, but the value you supply for the field used in the URL is entirely up to you -- `SecureRandom` is fine.

Comment: I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other two posters; you probably don't want to do this, and FriendlyID provides a nice way to work with alternate IDs for records.  That said, if you really do want to replace the id, you can just change it:

```
thing = Thing.new
thing.id = some_random_number_generator()
thing.save!
```

This was already covered in [Overriding id on create in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord).  Seriously consider not doing it unless you have a good reason.

Comment: The reason why is because this applications users to create private documents, so I'd prefer if the URL was random to stop users from guessing the URLs even if I were to make it so other users can't see the documents.

Comment: So to reinforce, you *don't* need to change the actual id, just the URL.  Changing the ID would be a huge (and entirely unnecessary) pain.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use FriendlyID here (or any other method to generate an alternate ID), and then just remove the route for ID-based lookups entirely, or simply rely on user authentication to prevent viewing based on IDs.  Security through obscurity isn't useful here.  Auto-incrementing IDs hold no information, and you'll want to block access to them in the controller either way.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm just looking to change the URL.

Comment: I've just updated the question.