# is there a callback which runs just before the transaction begins in rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just want to manipulate a model level object when it is newly created or it is updated.
For example, consider there is a test table with name attribute:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  custom_callback :hi
  def hi
    name = "h"
  end
end
m = Test.new(:name => "hello")
m.save
```

I just want to write a custom callback which should get executed before_validation and should get executed whenever a save or save! is called.  Ideally, I want some callback in rails 2.3 which should get executed and hook into ActiveRecord::Base. is there any gem to do this or does anyone know how to write a callback which get executed before 'before_validation' callback?

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `save` and `save!` methods to effectively inject the code. There's also the `initialize` method that might be appropriate depending on what you're trying to do. Also, `before_validation` runs before `validate`, so how much earlier do you need it to run exactly, and why?

Can you say more about **why** you want to do this? It sounds like you may have a design problem and you're trying to find a hack instead of addressing a more fundamental issue.

Comment: i don't want to override save and save! methods because it is little risky to override in all the models, i just want to manipulate the object when it is getting build so that i don' take it to transaction level .there are many places where before_validation methods doesn't get trigger and i want to address it this way

Comment: Okay, so can you explain more about what you're trying to do at this point in the callbacks and why you're trying to do it? The example code you provided is nice and all, but it doesn't get to the root of the code design issue that you're alluding to, and it doesn't explain your specific situation and/or why you want to go outside of the provided solution/callback structure, which makes it a little difficult to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: my issue is before_validation doesn't get trigger on association and little costly operation to save the association always. so i want to make sure this method is getting called always on the associations too..need to manipulate the object when i m constructing an object of the model

Comment: is there any way to write a custom call that gets called before the save or save! method is called?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is a way to add what is essentially another callback without patching ActiveRecord::Base. However, will `validates_associated` do what you want to do - triggering a method call on associated objects when the parent object is saved or updated? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: it does become little heavy whenever i save the parent object it will always validate the child object i just want to manipulate some attribute of the model.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html, http://thomasmango.com/2011/09/02/getting-to-know-active-support-callbacks/ i am just wondering if i can use this methods to implement

Comment: Can you simply alter the attribute in the controller before saving it?

Comment: there are many places where i need to change and really big so ideal place to handle is in model level i which i can move it

Comment: Regarding: api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html - yeah, that might work.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for before_save, which runs after validation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Please refer to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249475/ruby-on-rails-callback-what-is-difference-between-before-save-and-before-crea)

Comment: if i perform it in before_save there is a chance that validation may get skipped because you are validating some attribute and manipulating and storing some different attribute

Comment: you always can use `.valid?` to make sure it stills valid, or else fail the before_save.