# Rails: User specific sequential column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an inventory system, where a User has many inventory. We have a barcode column which needs to be sequential for each user.

For example:

Inventory Table:

```
id | user_id | barcode
 1 |       1 |       1
 2 |       1 |       2
 3 |       2 |       1
 4 |       2 |       2
 5 |       1 |       3
```

In the Inventory model I have

```
before_validation :assign_barcode, on: :create

def assign_barcode
  self.barcode = (user.inventories.order(barcode: :desc).first.try(:barcode) || 0) + 1
end
```

It generally works, but ran into a problem when seeding my db:

```
(1..5).each do
  user.inventories.build(...)
end
user.save
```

I end up with a bunch of inventories for `user` that have the same barcode. How can I ensure that inventories have unique barcodes even when adding inventories in bulk?

Comment: You'll need one of the suggestions that another user has made below, but in order to guarantee uniqueness you need to have database-level constraints or use table locking. Checkout the ActiveRecord documentation about concurrency and integrity http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: @WizardofOgz nice reference, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from:

```
before_validation :assign_barcode, on: :create
```

to:

```
before_create :assign_barcode
```

and it works as expected now, even when adding many `.builds` then calling save. Only downside is had to remove the barcode presence validator, but since it's automatically generated we should be OK.

Comment: Your method fixed the issue cuz before_create works as before_save in this scenario. It delays the barcode assignment to "save record" phase, which will do the work after all inventory objects are created. Here is a detailed [explaination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249475/ruby-on-rails-callback-what-is-difference-between-before-save-and-before-crea).

Answer (score 1):

You can build and save the object without saving the nested user object, which seems to cleanly call your validate method.  I'm pretty sure this is not as intended, but I am doing something similar for a project and seeded associated data as such.

Something like:

```
(1..5).each do
  inv = user.inventories.build
  inv.save
end
```

Comment: My situation is actually a bit more complicated than i described. Inventories belong to an Order sometimes, and there are some circular validation things going on that make `order.inventories.build` then `order.save` the only way to save an order.

Answer (score 1):

Calling 'build' will create a new inventory object but not save it automatically. Since the new created inventory was not saved into database, your query in method "assign_barcode" won't be able to find them, that's why they all end up with the same barcode: 1. What @trh suggested are correct, you need to save (either inv.save or user.save will do) a inventory immediately after build it.