# How to have two callbacks in "around_destroy" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Although this can be accomplished as follows:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_destroy :callback

  def callback
    puts 'callback1 before yield'
    puts 'callback2 before yield'
    yield
    puts 'callback1 after yield'
    puts 'callback2 after yield'
  end
end
```

But I wish to do the following:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_destroy :callback1, :callback2

  def callback1
    puts 'callback1 before yield'
    yield
    puts 'callback1 after yield'
  end

  def callback2
    puts 'callback2 before yield'
    yield
    puts 'callback2 after yield'
  end 
end
```

What would happen at the second 'yield' as the record could have been destroyed in first 'yield'? (assuming everything is running in one thread). How Rails handles this?

Or should I altogether avoid the second way?

Comment: It should work, if you remove the yield statement from callback methods. I'm not sure about the yield part. Can you give me an example of how you're yielding to callback methods.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998553/rails-around-callbacks.

Comment: I've tested it myself, and it's working perfectly fine. It's working, because I think active record wraps up these callbacks in a single transaction, and only make database changes, if these callbacks passes.

Comment: As, you can see from screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n86bpdtz8zmtcn/Screenshot%202015-06-22%2018.16.52.png?dl=0 that AR only executes SQL Query to find record, and once both callbacks runs successfully, then it commits the final query.

Comment: So Rails doesn't actually destroy the object at the point I did 'yield'? It seems it just creates a statement and executes that statement after these callbacks! Thank you Rahul! :-)

Comment: Do you have the answer you were looking for? Should I add the answer?

Comment: I got the answer, since I was thinking about the second yield on a destroyed object. You can very well post the answer! :-)

Comment: Done! @Sagar Ranglani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work without any issue, as Active Record wraps-up these callback methods in a single transaction.

> Since the object is destroyed in first yield, it seems the later is not feasible (assuming everything is running in one thread). How Rails handles this?

No, object isn't destroyed in first yield. Object is destroyed only after every callback method(except after_commit/after_rollback) has ran successfully.

Here's a quick example to illustrate this.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_destroy :callback1, :callback2
  after_commit :after_commit_callback

  def callback1
    puts "Inside First callback, before yield"
    yield
    puts "Inside First callback, after yield"
  end

  def callback2
    puts "Inside Second callback, before yield"
    yield
    puts "Inside Second callback, after yield"
  end

  def after_commit_callback
    puts "after commit callback message"
  end
end
```

Here's the required console commands:

```
[14] pry(main)> u = User.create(email: "rahul@example.com", password: "testing")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'rahul@example.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-22 13:01:12', 'rahul@example.com', '$2a$10$h5TYOd20JosN0oVa7ufK.OU3PnHJRi/X6CcTxy7UuDOqYLCIB...u', '2015-06-22 13:01:12')
   (25.8ms)  COMMIT
after commit callback message
=> #<User id: 8, email: "rahul@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$h5TYOd20JosN0oVa7ufK.OU3PnHJRi/X6CcTxy7UuDO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, name: nil, created_at: "2015-06-22 13:01:12", updated_at: "2015-06-22 13:01:12">
[15] pry(main)> u.destroy
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
Inside First callback, before yield
Inside Second callback, before yield
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 8
Inside Second callback, after yield
Inside First callback, after yield
   (4.0ms)  COMMIT
after commit callback message
=> #<User id: 8, email: "rahul@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$h5TYOd20JosN0oVa7ufK.OU3PnHJRi/X6CcTxy7UuDO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, name: nil, created_at: "2015-06-22 13:01:12", updated_at: "2015-06-22 13:01:12">
```